# How to set Essential JS Gantt chart first day of week

Tags: javascript, syncfusion

I try to modify [Essential JS](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript) Project Tracker example which is based on [ejgantt](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejgantt) component:

```
$("#gantt").ejGantt({
            dataSource: projectData,
            allowColumnResize: true,
            allowSorting: true,
            allowSelection: true,
            enableResize:true,
            enableContextMenu:true,
            taskIdMapping: "taskID",
            allowDragAndDrop:true,
            taskNameMapping: "taskName",
            startDateMapping: "startDate",
            showColumnChooser: true,
            showColumnOptions: true,
            progressMapping: "progress",
            durationMapping: "duration",
            endDateMapping: "endDate",
            childMapping: "subtasks",
            enableVirtualization: false,
            highlightWeekEnds: true,
            includeWeekend: false,
            scheduleStartDate: "02/01/2014",
            scheduleEndDate: "04/09/2014",
            scheduleHeaderSettings:{weekHeaderFormat : "d MMM yyyy" },
            resourceInfoMapping: "resourceId",
            resourceNameMapping: "resourceName",
            resourceIdMapping: "resourceId",
            resources: projectResources,
            predecessorMapping: "predecessor",
            showResourceNames:true,
            toolbarSettings: {
                showToolbar: true,
                toolbarItems: [ej.Gantt.ToolbarItems.Add,
                ej.Gantt.ToolbarItems.Edit,
                ej.Gantt.ToolbarItems.Delete,
                ej.Gantt.ToolbarItems.Update,
                ej.Gantt.ToolbarItems.Cancel,
                ej.Gantt.ToolbarItems.Indent,
                ej.Gantt.ToolbarItems.Outdent,
                ej.Gantt.ToolbarItems.ExpandAll,
                ej.Gantt.ToolbarItems.CollapseAll,
                ej.Gantt.ToolbarItems.Search]
            },
            editSettings: {
                allowEditing: true,
                allowAdding: true,
                allowDeleting: true,
                allowIndent: true,
                editMode: "cellEditing"
            },
            sizeSettings:{
                width:"100%",
                height:"100%"
            },
            dragTooltip: { showTooltip: true },
            showGridCellTooltip: true,
            treeColumnIndex:1
        });
    });
```

What I do not like about this component, is that the first day of week in this component is Sunday:

[image]

I know about [firstDayOfWeek](https://help.syncfusion.com/js/api/ejschedule#members:firstdayofweek) method, which however belongs to `ejschedule` component. So, I need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present there is no support for customizing the first day of week in ejGantt. For this we have already logged a feature request regarding this.
Please log on to our support website for further reference
https://www.syncfusion.com/Account/Logon?ReturnUrl=/support/directtrac

Regards,

Syncfusion Team.